# JSF access private/protected property of a super class

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, properties, superclass

I am very new to JSF and this is the first project I work on (got a bit too lazy with jsp) so please forgive me if the question is trivial.
So I have a Super Class Device

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Devices")
public class Device
{
    protected bool Authorized

    public bool isAuthorized()
      { return this.Authorized;}
    public void setAuthorized(bool Authorized)
      { this.Authorized = Authorized;}
}
```

and a sub class SensorDevice that extends the Super Class Device

```
public class SensorDevice extends Device
{
  // has its own properties which dont matter
}
```

and a Managed Bean UIDeviceManager

```
@ManagedBean(name = "DeviceManager")
@SessionScoped
public class UIDeviceManager 
{
   private List<SensorDevice> Pending;
   // in constructor, Pending List gets populated with the devices requiring Authorization
}
```

and an xhtml page which contains a Table for the Pending Devices

```
<p:dataTable var="device" value="#{DeviceManager.pending}">
<p:column headerText="Device Authorization">
<h:form>
<p:inputSwitch 
    value="#{device.isAuthorized()}" 
    binding="#{AuthorizationInputSwitch}" 
    offLabel="UnAuthorized" 
    onLabel="Authorized">    
<p:ajax 
    event="change" 
    listener="#{device.setAuthorized(AuthorizationInputSwitch.value)}" />
</p:inputSwitch>   
</h:form>               
</p:column>
```

Now unless the syntax in the xhtml is completely messed up (I tried my best there and would appreciate guidance), the function setAuthorized for that particular device instance should be called (even with the wrong input, but will sort that later by modifying the setter function), but that doesnt happen, the Ajax doesnt get called. Instead, the inputSwitch tries to update its "value property source" and attempts to look for a property isAuthorized() in the class SensorDevice which it fails to find.

Now I am aware that this could be easily solved by making the Boolean Authorized public in the super class but as you can see it is also a JPA entity that is persisted in a database to keep track of the devices, so the only option is to keep it protected.

So how do I update parameters of a Super class from a sub-class instance in a Managed Bean from a public function rather than direct access to the parameter itself (I thought JSF looked for the setters and getters but whatever)

Btw `value="#{device.isAuthorized()}"`works correctly but if I try the property directly it fails ( I guess its obvious at this point )

One last thing, if the approach/architecture is wrong, please advise on what is the correct layout to achieve this functionality. I am sure there is a standard way to integrate JSF and JPA without duplicating entities and wrappers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you must use field name in value attribute of InputSwitch component like this:

```
<p:inputSwitch 
    value="#{device.authorized}" 
    binding="#{AuthorizationInputSwitch}" 
    offLabel="UnAuthorized" 
    onLabel="Authorized">
```

Instead of:

```
<p:inputSwitch 
    value="#{device.isAuthorized()}" 
    binding="#{AuthorizationInputSwitch}" 
    offLabel="UnAuthorized" 
    onLabel="Authorized">
```

JSF will use isAuthorized and setAuthorized method (uses Java Beans standard convention to recognize getter and setter methods)

So i think you don't need the ajax part to call setter method.

Comment: Well my problem specifically IS that I CANT do that because Device class is a JPA entity  ... the field it self is protected (thus Myfaces cannot access it from its package. During the request it fails to see boolean Authorized and thus doesnt look for its getters and setters) . The function isAuthorized() is public and therefore can be accessed from the Myfaces package and Myfaces finds it no problem

Comment: when you use value="authorized", JSF will look for **isAuthorized** and **setAuthorized** method automatically. It is always like that in JSF, you don't need to define your member public, only standard setter and getter methods must be public.

Comment: so if the field is boolean Authorized, I must use device.authorized NOT device.Authorized ... must always be small letters ??? Thats the problem ?

Comment: yes you must use **"device.authorized"**. maybe that's your problem.

Comment: Yes, JSF follows [JavaBean conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans#JavaBean_conventions), which was the same for JSPs: you don't write "get" or "set" or "is" when accessing properties via methods.

Comment: some other notes:
1.it's not appropriate to use uppercase for variable names in java.
2.when you are using JPA Entities in JSF, be careful. The entity may be detached from JPA session and some getter methods throw exception (lazy loading).

Comment: I know that ... just didnt know that must use small letters, but its not working also ... now no request is being sent to update the field. Setter function is not being called, but it also doesnt fail to render, so it does find the field

Comment: have you defined getter and setter for **Pending** list property in your DeviceManager bean?

Comment: Thanks alot !! was one of those stupid things I sometimes get stuck in !!

Answer (score 1):

To emphasize Mojtaba's answer, this is how you access properties in JSF:

Facelets page:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:outputText value="#{myBean.entity.someBool}"/>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Managed bean:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class MyBean {
    private SomeEntity entity = new SomeEntity();
    public SomeEntity getEntity() {
        return entity;
    }
}
```

Entity classes:

```
public class SomeEntity extends SomeParent {
}

public class SomeParent {
    private boolean someBool = true;
    public boolean isSomeBool() {
        return someBool;
    }
    public void setSomeBool(boolean someBool) {
        this.someBool = someBool;
    }
}
```

JSF doesn't know or care that your objects are JPA entities, and standard inheritance and access rules apply.

### See also

- [JavaBean conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans#JavaBean_conventions)